# How to snap fit the line type in High charts using draggabe point js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I need help to snap to fit the draggable elements in High charts.

The "draggable-point.js" is used drag my line type object, but I need to snap fit draggable object to the near by y-axis.

Here I attached the fiddle linek. Here they done dragging without snap to fit to y-axis. link : http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/1914/

Thanks in advance.

```
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
interval = parseInt($("#scaleY").val());
 snapFit = parseInt($("#snapsPerLine").val());
 snapInterval = interval/snapFit;
var container = chart.container,
    dragPoint,
    dragX,
    dragY,
    dragPlotX,
    dragPlotY;
chart.redraw();
});
```

Comment: So what you mean here is to snap to nearby grid lines on the y-axis?

Comment: I recommend you to post your suggestion in our github (https://github.com/highslide-software/draggable-points/issues)

Comment: Raised the issue in github.Can u suggest some ideas to do this ..